# Android.mk file for Executable: accRuntimeTest

Tags: android

Can you please tell me where I can find the Android.mk file for Executable: accRuntimeTest?

I am getting the following error when I compile android source on ubuntu 9.10. I think it misses a linker flag to link a library 'dlsym', I just don't know where is the Android.mk file I should go and fix it?

```
Install: out/target/product/generic/system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
Install: out/target/product/generic/system/usr/keychars/qwerty2.kcm.bin
Install: out/target/product/generic/system/usr/keychars/tuttle2.kcm.bin
Copy: out/target/product/generic/system/etc/apns-conf.xml
host Executable: accRuntimeTest (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/accRuntimeTest_intermediates/accRuntimeTest)
host Executable: acc (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acc_intermediates/acc)
/usr/bin/ld: out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/accRuntimeTest_intermediates/runtimeTest.o: in function symbolLookup(void*, char const*):system/core/libacc/tests/runtimeTest.cpp:66: error: undefined reference to 'dlsym'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/accRuntimeTest_intermediates/accRuntimeTest] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score 0):

Android.mk is Android's own Makefile and your error seems to due to compiler dependent.
Try compiling your source in text mode in your PC.